# Why isn't 'ls' included as a package when I list all Debian packages installed?

Tags: debian, dpkg

When I list all packages with:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall > ~/Desktop/packages
```

the 'ls' command is not included. Is this because it is a GNU program and is bundled with Linux?

Excuse my naivety here. Thanks

Comment: This probably belongs to superuser.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ls` command is part of the [coreutils](https://wiki.debian.org/coreutils) package.